# jmeter Json extractor data use as body data

Tags: json, jmeter, json-extract, post-processor

i'm new in jmeter and i found that jmter json extractor can get data from the json respon, i already used the json extractor and i got the json path expression like this

[image]

my question, can i use the $.key as body data request "temporaryKey" variables?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure just replace the value with `${Temporary_key}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) reference, JMeter will resolve the variable value and replace it in the runtime.

More information:

- [Variabilize and Correlate the script](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)
- [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)